# ¿Cómo agregar objetos a un archivo binario en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo binario `archivoEmpleado = 'clases/empleado.bin'`

Y en un método `registroEmpleado` estoy solicitando datos para añadirlos al archivo binario:

```
def registroEmpleado(self):
    os.system("cls")
    print("    --- REGISTRO DE NUEVOS EMPLEADOS ---")
    codEmp = int(input("Código del empleado: "))
    nomEmp = input("Nombre del empelado: ")
    print("TIPOS DE EMPLEADO:\n[1].-Vendedor\n[2].-Cajero\n[3].-Despachador")
    tipEmp = int(input("Escriba el tipo de empleado a ser: "))
    with open(archivoEmpleado, 'wb') as e:
        e.write(registroE.Empleado(codEmp, nomEmp, tipEmp)) #Acá tengo que añadir el nuevo objeto 
    e.close()
    print("\n--- El registro del nuevo empleado se ha realizado correctamente. ---")
    print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar...")
    msvcrt.getch()
```

Sé que para escribir de forma binaria en un archivo `.bin` puede ser mediante un String de bytes, por ejemplo `e.write(b'Texto')` o se puede con un `bytearray`, pero mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo agregar al archivo binario el objeto como tal, y si es posible hacerlo?

Comment: En resumen: tienes un objeto en memoria y quieres guardarlo en un archivo para después volver a re-generarlo?

Comment: Sí, por ahora sólo los tengo almacenados en memoria, pero quiero saber si es posible almacenar en un archivo .bin el objeto como tal

Comment: Existen varias alternativas para serializar objetos en Python, pero lo más versátil parece ser usar JSON. Tiene la ventaja de ser un formato estándar, que puede ser leido por C, Java, Javascript, etc.